# Spotify - alerts for playing a new song

Tags: spotify

Is it possible to get Spotify to put up a notification listing the song name and artist everytime they start playing a new song like iTunes does? (On your desktop)

Here's an example:

[image]

Comment: Notifications where? On your desktop? In your browser? In a chat?

Comment: Wow, this is a good idea... Anyone know of a way?

Comment: I haven't used OSX for a while, but I used to do this with Growl, very simple.  http://growl.info/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but if you are on Linux using the "Spotify Linux Preview" client, you can use the [spotify-gnome script](https://github.com/jreese/spotify-gnome) to display very nice notifications, including cover art. The script was originally designed to make media keys work with the Spotify client, but for me the notification functionality is an equally important feature.

For OS X, there is [Spotify Notifications](http://spotify-notifications.citruspi.io/), for Windows `spotifynotifier`, both of which I haven't tested myself.

Comment: This is ridiculous: I could only post two links in my answer due to my lack of reputation. Here is the link to `spotifynotifier`: https://code.google.com/p/spotifynotifier/